# org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException during file upload

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload

I am trying to upload a dmp file in database. In my localhost(`tomcat`) everything is working perfect but after deployment to `linux` server on `tomcat` it fails to upload even 46 kb file. If file size is very small say 4 Kb then it uploads properly. Exception that i get is mentioned below:

**Exception:**

```
2013/Nov/06 17:39:58 ERROR [http-bio-13080-exec-21] (ArchiveImportServlet:call:72) - Exception in File Upload :Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /home/preuatuser/preuat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/temp/upload__659e2f43_1422d4e6c7b__7fff_00000017.tmp (No such file or directory)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /home/preuatuser/preuat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/temp/upload__659e2f43_1422d4e6c7b__7fff_00000017.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at com.nec.jp.netmiracle.server.archive.ArchiveImportServlet.call(ArchiveImportServlet.java:69)
    at com.nec.jp.netmiracle.server.BaseServlet.process(BaseServlet.java:141)
    at com.nec.jp.netmiracle.server.BaseServlet.doPost(BaseServlet.java:174)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.nec.jp.netmiracle.server.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/preuatuser/preuat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/temp/upload__659e2f43_1422d4e6c7b__7fff_00000017.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:165)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
```

Please provide any solution.

Comment: Are the permissions in the temp directory OK?

Comment: Do you have temp directory created in tomcat folder?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a higher sizeThreshold, an argument found on the constructor for [DiskFileItem](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.html).